# git: Peeking at newest commit of a non current local branch

Tags: git

I'm on the master branch. I want to see the commit hash of the last commit  in branch xxx.

I tried

```
git checkout xxx
git log | head
```

It's cumbercome. I bet there's a way to peek at this information without the heavy handed "checkout"

Any ideas?

Comment: If *all* you want is the hash, use `git rev-parse`, e.g., `git rev-parse master` or `git rev-parse xxx`.

Comment: @joshsverns Did you solve the problem? Please accept the proper answer

Answer (score 0):

You can append branch name after many commands which otherwise take a current branch or `HEAD` by default. For example:

```
$ git log <BRANCH>
```

or

```
$ git show <BRANCH>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use to get the last hash:

```
git rev-parse xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these below commands:

(1)

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%H" branch_name
```

(2)

```
git log branch_name --oneline -1
```

(3)

```
git log branch_name
```

(4)

```
git show branch_name
```

(5)

```
git rev-parse branch_name
```